# TimeoutException: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

I have an angular web project that is built in VS2017 Pro version 15.9.8. It compiles to target .net framework 4.6, but when run in IISExpress, it always time out. I've tried the following approaches:

- In the Startup.cs, I've specified `spa.Options.StartupTimeout` to be 2 minutes [but still time out]
- Inside `ClientApp` folder, perform `npm start`, `ng build`: [it always complains about `Error: Cannot find module '@angular/core/package.json'`.

A lot of people say just run `ng serve` directly from commandline, but the project was constructed in VS2017, so the `node_modules` folder is at the root directory of the project, instead of under the `ClientApp` folder. Also, the `@angular` folder doesn't contain the `core` folder, but instead, it is under the `@angular-devkit` folder.

So my questions are:

- How to fix the timeout problem if run from within VS2017?
- If run from commandline (e.g. `ng serve`), how to resolve the folder problem?

Answer (score 18):

Taken [from here](https://jasontaylor.dev/asp-net-core-angular-9-upgrade/) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17277), it appears to work well in .NET Core 3 and Angular 9. Modify the way the Angular server is started in `package.json` to add a dummy `echo`:

```
"start": "ng serve"
```

becomes

```
"start": "echo Starting && ng serve"
```

Comment: This answer works, but it should be "serve" instead of "server"

Comment: Oops, typo fixed.

Comment: this helped for me also :-)

Answer (score 16):

**ASP.NET Core >= 3.0**

If you are using asp.net core 3.0 then you should not use `UseAngularCliServer` instead. You should use asp.net as a proxy for development. more detail is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#run-ng-serve-independently)

```cs
app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                }
            });
```

open command widnow, go to ClientApp and start npm server.

```sh
c:\your\project\directory\> cd ClientApp
c:\your\project\directory\> npm start
```

**ASP.NET Core 2.0**

`refresh(F5)` your browser or increase timeout for SPA configuration

```cs
app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                    spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200); // <-- add this line
                }
            });
```

In the development environment, npm builds an angular app before serving. some times build takes longer than 120 seconds.

Comment: For me the error says "...the timeout period of 0 seconds". What is the default value for the startup timeout? Do you mean to say the default timeout is 120 secs?

Comment: The Microsoft doc you linked to doesn't say using `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` is the only way to do it in 3.0, just that you can use it to avoid waiting for the angular server to start up every time you change and run your C# code. `UseAngularCliServer` is still a valid way of hosting Angular in Asp.net core 3

Answer (score 13):

Refreshing (`F5`) the page solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 13):

I'm running **Angular 9**, **.net core 3.1** and **VS 2019 Community**.  I started gettign the issue after upgrading to the latest version of Angular.  After reading other issues, I tried a few steps, including increasing the timeout, but nothing worked.

The change I made to get it working, was to set `"progress" : true`, in the `angular.json` file.  To locate the correct place, it's under `serve`.

```
 "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "xxx:build",
            "progress": true
          },
```

Comment: Merci, Monsieur!

Answer (score 9):

Here is a workaround. Tested using ASP .NET Core 3.1

1.In your Startup class, replace the spa.UseAngularCliServer invocation with the following:

```
spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
```

2.In a command prompt, switch to the ClientApp subdirectory, and launch the Angular CLI development server:

```
cd ClientApp
npm start
```

Source: [ASP.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thank you so much this saves so much time so I don't need to restart the server when I change the backend.

Comment: This is what I need, a separate process for starting them both, thanks

Comment: you mean every time we need to start angular app we will start it manually from command prompt?

Answer (score 3):

Try (CTRL+F5) to force a reload from server and it solves the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, refreshed the browser again a bit late and it worked perfectly.

**Resolution Note**: We encounter the same behavior which is due to the compilation of source files taking longer than the permitted timeout limit to connect to Node/Angular CLI.

If you refresh the browser it will eventually connect and you are good to go.
Once your source files are compiled the timeout no longer occurs.

I also set a timeout for SPA configuration like below (80 sec).

[image]

Ref. [The Angular CLI process times out first time debug is run](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1512)

**Update 2.0** With Angular 10.0 and .Net Core 3.1

I've also set **progress: true** in serve section of angular.json file

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've to increase the time more:                                                
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
 {
 spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 360);
 spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
}

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience, but with .NET Core 2.1 and 2.2.

**Browsed experiences:**

[This](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/54520629-the-angular-cli-process-times-out-first-time-debug-is-run) could help (related to .NET Core as opposed to .Net Framework 4.6):

The main difference is the 'folder problem'. In `.NET Core`, the `ClientApp` has all the angular folders in one place.

**My experience (using .NET Core 2.1 and 2.2):**

- Run `ng serve` in command prompt in `ClientApp` (i.e. the folder containing angular)
- Then, run `dotnet run` in command prompt in the project folder.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Running project through `dotnet run` command gives you the actual error. In my case it was permission issue to bin/debug directory of my project. Running VS as Administrator solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, The CLI isn't loading up fast enough for .net core to "hook onto" it.  So, put the timeout to like 30 seconds, and just wait. Try refreshing a few times. Mine took upwards of 5 minutes for some perspective.